# Add a button that closes the popup with popup.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

I'm having troubles creating an exit button for the following script.
I'm using popup.js from http://docs.toddish.co.uk/popup/.
It sais that in order to do it we should use popup.close() from inside the object. But there are no examples and I can't get it to work. Does anyone have an idea?

JSFiddle link = http://jsfiddle.net/andrewallen817/bedhhu1o/3/

Html:

```
<a href=#txt class="popup" >Click here</a>

<div id="txt" style="display:none">
    <h1>This is a title</h1>
    <p>this is some text</p>
    <button>close</button>    

</div>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('.popup').popup();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it for you by looking at the doc. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bedhhu1o/4/)

```
$(function () {
    $('.popup').popup({
        afterOpen: function () {
            var popup = this;
            $('button').click(function () {
                popup.close();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

You might want to specify which button you want to give the popup.close() or else every button will have it.